# Dlib - How do I use the loss_mean_squared_multioutput training label type?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, dlib

ML and DLib beginner here, so please excuse me if the question meanders a little.

I've been looking at some of the example projects in the Dlib documentation, and roughly understand the example found here:

http://dlib.net/dnn_introduction_ex.cpp.html

The example looks straightforward, enough for me to grasp how to compile a working example.

What I would like to do however, is attempt to use a `loss_mean_squared_multioutput` layer in the place of the `loss_multiclass_log` found in the example, as I think it will be a better fit for my model.

To give a brief, high level description of the problem I have, it's a regression problem with 5 outputs. On training, I would like to feed in an 'image', and train the network on how valuable any one of those 5 outputs might be, in relation to that input.

So for example, if I feed in (pseudocode):

```
input = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I would like the output to produce something like this

```
output = [0, 0.1, 0, 0.5, -1]
```

With that in mind, if the labels for `loss_mean_squared_multioutput` are `matrix<float>`, is this roughly how I should go about using it?:

```
loss_multiclass_log<fc<5...
trainer.train([list of matrix<float>], [list of matrix<float 1, 5> = 0, 0.1, 0, 0.5, -1]);
```

Also, if this all seems totally misguided and nonsensical to you after reading through, by all means, please correct me. I would appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help out anyone who might have wondered the same thing, there's an example in the Dlib test suite -
 https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/dlib/test/dnn.cpp#L2343

The idea of how to use it is mostly right, but ensure that where you have the following:

```
loss_multiclass_log<fc<5...
```

You need to use a single column matrix in the trainer, like this:

```
// Use "matrix<float 5, 1>", not "matrix<float 1, 5>"...
trainer.train(input..., [list of matrix<float 5, 1>...);
```

Hope that helps.